# `git rebase --skip` but changes still included

Tags: git, version-control, rebase

I'm learning Git rebase :
I create a conflict situation to test the behavior of `git rebase -i` commands.
I `git rebase --skip` when the attended conflict happened,
but a other conflict happened after, and the "skipped" data reappear in a other commit.

At the end : No data lost,
What `--skip` have done ?

Here the conflict situation I created to test :

- I have my current code saved in a commit : "*saved*"

```
[code]
```

- I add a feature -> ctrl + s -> `git add .` -> New commit : "*feature*", everything's ok.

```
[code]
[feature]
```

- And something I will skip for the test -> ctrl + s -> `git add .` -> New commit : "*skip*".

```
[code]
[feature]
skip
```

- Finally something after -> ctrl + s -> `git add .` -> New commit : "*new feature*".

```
[code]
[feature]
skip
[new feature]
```

The situation is set.

I now launch the rebase test with `git rebase -i HEAD~4`,
and move the "*skip*" commit up (before "*feature*"), to generate a conflict.

```bash
pick 9fc9fbd save
pick 036ad6a skip
pick da647db feature
pick 8763ea1 new feature
```

Let's go, the conflict is here :

```bash
Auto-merging git-modif-annulation.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in git-modif-annulation.md
error: could not apply 036ad6a... skip
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 036ad6a... skip
```

So i `git rebase --skip` as intended :
-> "*skip*" is skipped,
-> "*feature*" is applied,
and...

That wasn't expected :
New conflict on "*new feature*" :

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
  skip
  [new feature]
>>>>>>> new feature
```

`[new feature]` should be here, but why `skip` is ?

That make me rethought all I knew about how Git work :
I thought only changes was saved in commits, in an incremental way.
But if `skip` appear in "*new feature*", it mean that each commit is a new complete save of the  project ? Or maybe just the file ?

Anyway : Skipping "*skip*" had no effect.
But the [GitHub docs about this](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/resolving-merge-conflicts-after-a-git-rebase) say it should :

> You can run `git rebase --skip` to completely skip the commit. **That means that none of the changes introduced by the problematic commit will be included**.

What did i miss ?

### Edit :

I try to drop the "*skip*" commit instead : same result.

```bash
pick 9fc9fbd save
pick da647db feature
drop 036ad6a skip
pick 8763ea1 new feature
```

Drop the "*skip*" commit generate the same conflict when the next commit is apply :
All the modifications brought by "*skip*" are brought by the next commit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the cherry pick effect (note: `git rebase` is one way to batch a sequence of individual cherry-picks).

When you cherry-pick a commit, `git` resorts to a 3 way merge, but using a merge base which is not represented by the existing history.

Let me try to illustrate :

```
# starting point:

* (HEAD -> master) master head commit
| * (feature) c2 - feature head commit
| * c1
| * p
| |
|/
*
*
...
```

---

if you currently are on `master`, and run `git cherry-pick c1` :

git will resolve a 3 way merge, using :

- `HEAD` as "ours"
- `c1` as "theirs"
- -> and `p` as base (<- that's the changing point)

The mnemonic I use to remember this:

- you need to identify 3 commits,
- obviously, `HEAD` will be involved,
- to "get the diff for `c1`" in git, you actually need `c1` *and his parent*

`git` behaves exactly as if it was solving the following merge :

```
* (HEAD -> master) master head commit  #
| * c1                                 # <- not your current history
 \|                                    # 
  * p                                  # 
$ git merge c1
```

so the *diff* you see on the "ours" side is the diff between `p` and `HEAD` -- even though `p` and `HEAD` are, in the sequence of commits, not directly related.

---

Now suppose you cherry-pick two commits: `git cherry-pick c1 c2`  (note : this would be the same as `git rebase --onto master p c2`)

For some reason (conflicts ...) you decide to skip over `c1`.
On the next step (next step is `git cherry-pick c2`), the "ours" side of the 3 way diff will be the diff between `c1` and `master`.

So, even though you haven't kept `c1` on top of master, the *diff* that will be presented to you *still relates to the content of `c1`*.

---

Coming back to your example: `c1` would be `skip`, `c2` would be `new feature`.

Even though you skipped `c1`, when trying to cherry-pick `c2`, git still tries to reconcile a diff saying "'skip' line was deleted" (`git diff skip *current state of rebase*` <- you chose to not include `skip` there) with "add 'new feature' after line 'skip'" (`git diff skip new_feature`).
This is why you see this conflict.

---

More generally, this is the reason why, when doing a rebase, you may have a feeling of fixing the same conflict over and over again :

- you fix it when replaying commit `n`,
- but when replaying commit `n+1`, you will still have a diff which doesn't reflect this first resolution.

There is a git feature to mitigate this problem : `git rerere` -- acronym for "Reuse recorded resolution"

To enable it:

```
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

It somehow stores the resolution you provide for conflicts, and when it identifies the same conflict again, reapplies the same resolution.

See [`git help rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) for more details.

---

[edit: following your comment]

I warmly recommend to read: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging
among other things it explains the two different standards to display conflicts in file.

When you inspect the content of a file which has conflicts, the default display format is the so called `merge` format :

```
$ cat file 
[code]
[feature]
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
skip
[new feature]
>>>>>>> 0ecdc58 (new feature)
```

It shows, for each diff hunk that was determined to conflict, the `ours` version and the `theirs` version, but it doesn't display the `base` version.

You can ask git to switch to the other `diff3` format for a specific file:

```
# note: don't do this if you had already fixed part of the conflicts in 'file'
$ git checkout --conflict=diff3 file
Recreated 1 merge conflict
$ cat file
[code]
[feature]
<<<<<<< ours
||||||| base
skip
=======
skip
[new feature]
>>>>>>> theirs
```

With that view it is more obvious that the version in `ours` is actually a *deletion*, while the version in `theirs` is an addition, with an incompatible context.

If you think that the `diff3` format is the one you always want, you set the config parameter:

```
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Comment: That's help a lot TY.

Comment: And that explain the conflict.
But you said : _the "ours" side of the 3 way diff will be the diff between c1 and master_,   
So i should have in the conflicted file :  
 `<<<<<<< HEAD
  skip
=======
  [new feature]
>>>>>>> new feature`  
But I have :  
`<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
  skip
  [new feature]
>>>>>>> new feature`  -> skip is the _theirs_ side, not on the _ours_ site...

Comment: @Lex: this is the `merge` style for conflict blocks in your file, which doesn't display "base". The absence of line on the HEAD part is actually a deletion in your specific example. Try: `git checkout --conflict=diff3 <file>`. (got it from https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging which is worth the reading)